# Cómo se omiten caracteres especiales en un lookbehind en regex

Tags: python, regex

Por ejemplo, si quiero encontrar textos con un patrón "asd" que no sean precedidos por un número, inclusive si tienen puntos o paréntesis de por medio.

Para el siguiente texto:

```py
test_str = (
    "wfasd\n"
    "Aasd\n"
    "D.asd\n"
    "E(asd)\n"
    "No debería detectar:\n"
    "3asd\n"
    "2.asd\n"
    "1(asd)\n"
    "1.(asd)\n"
    "0asd"
    )
```

La salida debería ser:

```py
True wfasd
True Aasd
True D.asd
True E(asd)
False No debería detectar:
False 3asd
False 2.asd
False 1(asd)
False 1.(asd)
False 0asd
```

Pero la salida es:

```py
True wfasd
True Aasd
True D.asd
True E(asd)
False No debería detectar:
False 3asd
True 2.asd
True 1(asd)
True 1.(asd)
False 0asd
```

El código de prueba es:

```py
import re

regex = r"(?<!\d)[\.\()]?asd"

test_str = (
    "wfasd\n"
    "Aasd\n"
    "D.asd\n"
    "E(asd)\n"
    "No debería detectar:\n"
    "3asd\n"
    "2.asd\n"
    "1(asd)\n"
    "1.(asd)\n"
    "0asd"
    )


for line in test_str.split("\n"):
    # tempLine=re.sub("[\(\[\.\]\)?]","",line)
    match = re.search(regex, line) is not None
    print(match, line)
```

Se podría lograr eliminando temporalmente los caracteres especiales con `tempLine=re.sub("[\(\[\.\]\)?]","",line)` pero me intriga si es posible con una sola línea de regex, y porqué el cuantificador "codicioso" (`[\.\()]?`) no lo está siendo...

*Preferiblemente una respuesta en python, aunque no restringido a este.

Comment: Por qué en donde "La salida debería ser" `E(asd)` es True? Esta procedido por un `(` ¿no deberia ser False?

Comment: +1 por una pregunta bien planteada y trabajada.

Comment: @multiple Gracias por el interés, la pregunta va enfocada a que se ignore `(` y otros símbolos, así que se tendría que ver el carácter/símbolo que va antes de `(`. En el caso de `E(asd)` si ignoramos `(` la letra que tendría que revisar es `E` la cual al no ser un número debería ser `True`.

Comment: El problema es `[\.\()]?`. Esta parte puede o no ocurrir. Python intenta calzar `2.asd` y reduce la exp. reg. a `(?<!\d)asd`, que si calza, pues `asd`no está precedido de un digito, sino de un "." Lo más sano sería utilizar r"asd" y luego descartar los resultados que comiencen con digito.

Comment: Dicho de otra manera, el patrón `(?<!\d)[\.\()]?asd` son dos patrones: `(?<!\d)[\.\()]asd` y `(?<!\d)asd`. Python los intenta hasta encontrar uno que calce. El último calza.